# How can I check that a song isn't already added to the playlist? (".Contains" won't work)

Tags: c#

Purpose of this is to check that the users response is within (songNames) than based on that it will check if its already been added to the music playlist (to prevent multiple entries of the same song)

```
    private void btnAddToPlaylist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string usersInput = txtBoxSongName.Text + ".mp3";
        usersInput = usersInput.ToLower();

        List<string> songNames = new List<string>(new string[] { "rock and roll.mp3", "wake up.mp3", "floating away.mp3", "inside.mp3" });

        if (songNames.Contains(usersInput))
        {
            var customPlaylist = player.newPlaylist("Custom Playlist", "");

            if (!customPlaylist.Contains(usersInput))
            {
                customPlaylist.appendItem(player.newMedia(usersInput));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This song is already in your playlist.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The following song is not available.");
        }
```

Comment: What is `customPlaylist`? We cannot help you with some opaque user-defined types, unless you reveal them to us.

Comment: Enumerable contains works with primary datatypes only. To check complex object implement IEqualityComparer interface. [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Contains works fine. Note the spelling and the extension!

Answer (score 0):

As @Kaenbyou Rin said in comment it's not clear what's `customPlaylist`. So, I assume it's a `List<string>`.

`Contains` method only checks if your list contains a **exact match** of what you're passing to it. So, if `userInput` is a part of a string that you have in `customPlaylist` you can check it like this:

```
if (!customPlaylist.Any(x=>x.Contains(userInput)))
```

**Note:** If `customPlaylist` is a complex object you should implement Equals and GetHashCode methods in that object, and then `Contains` will work properly.

Comment: and GetHashCode method should be overridden as well along with Equals() .

Comment: @aspxsushil Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Compare issue?

Change

```
if (!customPlaylist.Contains(usersInput))
```

to

```
if (!customPlaylist.Any(m=> m.Title == usersInput)) //Title, Name, or whatever your use as the Id.
```

## 2. New playlist issue?

### 2A

After the 1st lookup succeeds you always create a new playlist.

```
var customPlaylist = player.newPlaylist("Custom Playlist", "");

if (!customPlaylist.Contains(usersInput))
```

If `.newPlaylist` doesn't contain tracks already in the list you are searching in an empty list.

### 2B

After you appendItem the track is the list assigned as the player's list? If not then next time you ask the player for .newPlaylist it will not contain the added item.

Comment: Yeah I forgot it'd just overwrite the "customPlaylist" list for each time it checks. Even after that though i'm getting errors regarding WMP like:                                                    'IWMPPlaylist' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first arguement of type 'IWMPPlaylist' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)

Comment: You need `using System.Linq`